# this.setState doesnt change the state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So, I am trying to change the state using previous state, but it doesnt change whatsoever. Can anyone tell me whats the problem pls?

```
handleToggleComplete = (key, complete) => {


       itemIndex = this.state.items.findIndex(item => item.key === key);

       console.log('before: ', this.state.items);

       this.setState(prevState => {
         return {
           ...prevState,
             items: [
               ...prevState.items,
               prevState.items[itemIndex]: {
               completed: true,
               text: 'hardcoded value'
             }
           ]
         }
       });

       console.log('after: ', this.state.items);
   }
```

Logs:

```
before:  
[{…}]

{key: 1530370127933, completed: false, text: "some value"}

after:  
[{…}]

{key: 1530370127933, completed: false, text: "some value"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.setState` doesn't change the state immediately. It re-renders the component and with the updated state. So naturally you will not see the updated state in your function.

Here is an app that demonstrates exactly that. I displayed in the console the current value of the state and render it with the button:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      myState: 0
    }
  }
  
  handleClick () {
     let incrementState = this.state.myState + 1
     console.log('State before increment:', this.state.myState)
     this.setState({myState: incrementState})
    console.log('State AFTER increment:', this.state.myState, '\nSee, it\'s still the same BUT the component has been updated (look at the number)!')
  }
  
  render() {
    const { myState } = this.state
    return (<div>
        <h1>{myState}</h1>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Increment State</button>
      </div>);
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```